# Sorting items in OPC Server

Tags: sorting, client, items, opc

We are trying to implement an OPC Server, with a specific objects structure, as you can see in the following example:

- Node X

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
  - Item 4
  - Item 5
  - Item 6
  - Item 7
  - ... (till 300)
- Node Y

  - ...

But, for some strange reason, in several OPC clients the items are shown like this:

- Node X

  - Item 3
  - Item 11
  - Item 22
  - Item 33
  - Item 44
  - Item 55
  - Item 4
  - ... (till 300)
- Node Y

  - ...

Our main problem is about sorting the items in the list. As you can see in the screenshot the items are not shown sorted in the OPC client, and we have tried several OPC clients and some of them have a special option to show the items in a sorted way and some others no.

The thing is... if we are creating a generic OPC Server for all the existing OPC clients in the market... it is responsibility of the server to serve the items sorted, right? or... is it responsibility of the client?

Conceptually, which is the correct way?

My feeling is that the OPC Server should give all the items sorted anyway, but I'm not sure if it is possible and standard.

Otherwise, there are a lot of SCADA's in the world, for sure, that trying to show the list of items in a screen will show them not sorted, as in the sample provided, and this is a big problem when you have around 300 items in a list.

Thanks for your collaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of items has no significance in OPC specifications. In addition, OPC does not "tell" the servers in which order they should enumerate the items, and it does not "tell" the clients in which order they should display them.

If you want to see the items ordered in a specific way, the best you can do is to develop your OPC server so that it indeed enumerates them in that order. When done this way, the OPC clients that do NOT sort the incoming items in any way will list them in the order you have chosen. With OPC clients that decide to sort the items somehow, you are out of luck - they will always do it their way. I would argue that good OPC clients that present the items to the user should allow them to influence the ordering, but that's up to them.

Also, the example order you presented somewhat resembles what happens when strings are sorted using the "dumb" ordering, and not looking for the natural number order in them. This leads to number ordering where numbers with less digits are interspersed within numbers with more digits, instead of numbers being taken for their numerical value. But, if that was the case, you example would like more like this:

- > - Node X

> -- Item 1
>   -- Item 10
>   -- Item 11
>   -- Item 12
>   -- ...
>   -- Item 2
>   -- Item 20
>   -- Item 21
>   -- Item 22
>   -- ...
>   -- Item 3
>   -- Item 30
>   -- ...
>
> - Node Y
>
> Isn't that what you are getting? (but regardless of it, the first part of the answer applies anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The problem is that we are implementing the OPC Server using a toolkit from Softing, and they tell us that it is responsibility of the client the sorting issue.
By other hand, we are talking to Intouch representatives, where Intouch is a comercial SCADA, and its OPC client does not have any kind of option to change the order.

Therefore... it seems there is no solution at all. Well, unless we change the toolkit or the SCADA, obviously.

Comment: Regarding the example provided, it seems sorted randomly. I understand your comment about the "dumb" ordering, but have in account that the current values are not following this ordering: 3, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 4, instead of 11, 22, 3, 33, 4, 44, 55

Comment: Softing is right in saying, basically the same as I described, that it is a client responsibility to sort the items. The bottom line is that the OPC specs do not provide for "server-defined" ordering, it all depends on the clients. In the end, you are asking for something that the underlying technology does not support. This is likely not an answer that you want to hear, but it is a correct answer nevertheless.

Comment: I understand your opinion, but I cannot understand that the server could give the items with different order every time that the client connects, for instance. In your opinion this is ok, right? If every time you connect you have the items in a different order.... Is this acceptable? Is this normal???

Comment: It should serve the data every time with the same order, right? Then... there is some order, right? Introduction order, alphabetically, .... My opinion is that the server should serve the items in a known order, not randomly

Comment: Technically, there is an order - because it is implemented using an enumerator, with sequential access. Similarly, if it were implemented .e.g. using an array, there would be some order as well, given by the element indices. But because the OPC specification treats is more like a "set", not a "sequence", the order should be irrelevant to the receivers, and therefore the server is not required (by the OPC spec) to use the same order every time.