# How does OPC order items?

Tags: opc, opc-da

I'm working on an OPC(DA) server that creates a collection of server items and sends them to an OPC client. Each item has a "name" value that determines the order that the items are displayed in. The name of each item is structured as:

```
Sites.<SiteID>.CurrentValue
```

So the data might look something like:

```
Sites.0001.CurrentValue
Sites.0002.CurrentValue
Sites.0003.CurrentValue
Etc.
```

Or in a tree format:

```
Sites:
  0001:
    CurrentValue
  0002:
    CurrentValue
  0003:
    CurrentValue
  Etc.
```

Since the items are ordered by name and the only variable part of the item name is the site ID, the items are effectively ordered by site ID. The problem occurs when the OPC client displays the items. The order that they're displayed in is totally different:

```
Sites:
  6219
  13501
  13502
  4000
  4001
  626262
  4002
  4003
  4004
  4005
  4006
  4007
  4008
  0030
  4009
  0200
  79791
  Etc.
```

I've been trying to infer some kind of logical ordering system that would give this result, but I'm just not seeing anything. I have tried this with several OPC clients (Matrikon, dOPC, KEP) and they are all consistently presenting items in the above order, which leads me to believe there is some kind of universal OPC ordering system, but I've not been able to find anything.

My hope is that, if I can find out how OPC is ordering these items, I can order the items in the OPC server, such that they will get displayed in a logical order in the OPC client.

My server is Advosol-based (I don't have enough reputation to create a new tag).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341994/sorting-items-in-opc-server . In short, there is no prescribed order of items in OPC.

Comment: You mentioned in that post that you could order your items, such that the OPC client would enumerate them in the order that you want. Is there no way to know how any given OPC client is enumerating the items?

Comment: The client is free to show the items in any way it feels fit. Most clients will either a) show them in the order they were enumerated by the servers, or b) sort them alphabetically. For clients that show the items in the order they were enumerated by the server, you may modify your server to enumerate them in the order you prefer - that certainly won't harm anything. But you have no influence over other clients that may decide to sort or shuffle the items in some way.

Comment: Neither of those things seems to be true in my case. I've tried several (the most common) OPC clients, so if it were typical for them to display items either alphabetically or in the order that they were enumerated by the server, you would expect at least one of them to abide by that rule. I suppose it must be the case that these clients (dOPC, matrikon, KEP) do have their own way of ordering items. I personally just don't see the logic behind their methods of ordering, if that is the case.

Comment: A real OPC(da) client is some type of HMI/SCADA/DCS etc. software which display the data to the user for some interaction. For these clients the order of the items is totally irrelevant. Your "ordering" means nothing for real clients...